# Ошибка при запуске .py из командной строки - "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str"

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql, sql-server, database-cursor

При запуске файла "bot.py" из командной строки появляется следующая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 20, in <module>
    text = '<b>Класс проблемы: </b>'+row[0]+\
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
```

В гугле решения не нашел. Вот мой код:

```
import telebot
import config
import random
import requests
import pyodbc

server = 'TELEGRAMGATEWAY\MSSQL_TELEGRAM'
database = 'Имя базы'
username = 'Имя пользователя'
password = 'Пароль'

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)

cursor = cnxn.cursor()

cursor.execute('SELECT TOP 1 className, eqpName, partName, nodeName, core, opisanie, FIO, serviceName FROM smsTelegram ORDER BY problemID DESC')


for row in cursor:
    text = '<b>Класс проблемы: </b>'+row[0]+\
            '\n<b>Оборудование: </b>'+row[1]+\
            '\n<b>Часть оборудования: </b>'+row[2]+\
            '\n<b>Узел: </b>'+row[3]+\
            '\n<b>Суть: </b>'+row[4]+\
            '\n<b>Детали: </b>'+row[5]+\
            '\n<b>Служба: </b>'+row[7]+\
            '\n<b>Специалист: </b>'+row[6]
    
text = text.replace("<br>", " ")
def send_telegram(text: str):
    token = "ХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХ"
    url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot"
    channel_id = ХХХХХХХХХ
    url += token
    method = url + "/sendMessage"

    r = requests.post(method, data={
         "chat_id": channel_id,
         "text": text,
         "parse_mode": 'html'
          })

    if r.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception("post_text error")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    send_telegram(text)
```

Comment: Пробовали проверить тип `row[0]`?

Comment: да, проверял, пишет, что str

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по тексту ошибки, в одном из `row[i]` - находится `None`.

Воспроизведение ошибки:

```
In [48]: "string" + None
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-69dded62479b> in <module>
----> 1 "string" + None

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
```

---

Для того, чтобы вычитать результат запроса (`"SELECT ..."`), выполненного при помощи `cursor.execute(SQL)`, надо воспользоваться методом `cursor.fetchone()` или `cursor.fetchall()`:

```
cursor.execute(query)
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    # ...
```

или воспользоваться однострочником:

```
for row in cursor.execute(query).fetchall():
    # ...
```

---

**UPD:** внимательнее присмотрелся к вашему запросу - если я правильно понял и ваша цель - получить единственную строку (`TOP 1`), то можно обойтись без цикла:

```
qry = '''SELECT TOP 1
           className, eqpName, partName, nodeName, core, opisanie, serviceName, FIO
         FROM smsTelegram
         ORDER BY problemID DESC'''  

text = None
row = cursor.execute(qry).fetchone()
if row:
    text = '<b>Класс проблемы: </b>{}'\
            '\n<b>Оборудование: </b>{}'\
            '\n<b>Часть оборудования: </b>{}'\
            '\n<b>Узел: </b>{}'\
            '\n<b>Суть: </b>{}'\
            '\n<b>Детали: </b>{}'\
            '\n<b>Служба: </b>{}'\
            '\n<b>Специалист: </b>{}'
    text = text.format(*row).replace("<br>", " ")
```

Comment: попробовал первый способ - не помогло, после второго появилась ошибка Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 29, in <module>
    text = text.replace("<br>", " ")
NameError: name 'text' is not defined

Comment: @Homie, вы все еще получаете ошибку `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str` ?

Comment: @Homie, у вас опасный стиль кодирования. Если запрос не вернет ни одной строки, то переменная `text`  будет не объявлена - именно об этом вам и сообщает интерпретатор

Comment: `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str` больше не получаю

Comment: аааа, спасибо Вам огромное, Ваш запрос стал просто спасением.